# Spring Cloud Gateway Netty Metrics

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-gateway, reactor-netty

We are using Spring Cloud Gateway in our production environment and we are trying to expose the Netty connection pool metrics. I couldn't find a configuration to enable the Netty connection metrics in the gateway. I think the only only way to expose the metrics is to override the ConnectionProvider in the GatewayHttpClient class. Is there any alternative that can be used to expose the Netty metrics without needing to override the Gateway internal code?

Answer (score 0):

This is because `HttpClient` created by `Spring Cloud Gateway` not enable metric，you can modify `HttpClient` like this：

```
@Component
public class HttpClientConfig implements BeanPostProcessor {

    @Override
    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
        if (bean instanceof HttpClient) {
            HttpClient client = (HttpClient) bean;
            return client.metrics(true, s -> s);

        }
        return bean;
    }
}
```